# Denote " ∥f−g∥<δ in X " to mean that ∥f(x)−g(x)∥≤δ and ∥f′(x)−g′(x)∥≤δ ...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Let $f,g: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ differentiable in the open $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $\delta >0$ and $X\subset U$.

Denote " $\Vert f-g\Vert_{\star} < \delta$ in $X$ " to mean that $Sup \{ \ \vert f(x)-g(x)\vert, \vert f^{\prime}(x)-g^{\prime}(x)\vert :x \in X \ \}\leq \delta$.

Show that if $\varphi: W \rightarrow U$ is differentiable in the open $W\subset \mathbb{R}^{k} $ then given $K\subset W$ compact and $\varepsilon>0$, there $\delta >0$ such that $\Vert f-g\Vert_{\star}<  \delta$ in $\varphi(K)\Rightarrow \Vert f\circ \varphi-g\circ \varphi\Vert_{\star}< \varepsilon$ in $K$.

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks.

Comment: 1) The notations are horrible. There are two norms (I assume a $C^0$ norm, and a $C^1$ norm that you define in the first sentence). Use a subscript to distinguish between the two norm, $\|f-g\|_{C^0}$ for instance. 2) You are given $f$, $g$ and $h$ with $\|f-g\|_{C^1} \le \delta$. What is $\|f \circ h -g \circ h \|_{C^1}$ equal to? How do you bound it?

Comment: sorry, did not know this notation. will edit.